# Sailed back safe

Tags: predicate-adjectives

See this problem:

> 1. How about the ship then?
> 2. It sailed back _____.
>
> A. safe
>
> B. safely
>
> C. safety

The answer is A. Although it's understandable, I still wondered why B isn't the answer?

Comment: Who says that the answer is A?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, B is a much better answer.

It's true that we can say *He came back safe and sound* (he was safe and well when he arrived), but *sailed* refers to the ship's journey, not just its arrival, so an adverb seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+sailed+back+safe%2Che+came+back+safe%2Che+sailed+back+safely%2Csailed+back+safe%2C+sailed+back+safely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20came%20back%20safe%3B%2Cc0) for 
_he sailed back safe,

he came back safe,

he sailed back safely,

sailed back safe,

sailed back safely_

flatline for all but _he came back safe_. While the depictive (adjective) usage is arguably not ungrammatical, it seems unidiomatic in this case (with _sailed_).

Answer (score 0):

> It sailed back safe.

= the ship sailed back and the ship was safe. (It is quite possible that the ship was badly damaged and the journey was far from safe. It was only when it arrived that the ship and crew could be said to be safe.)

> It sailed back safely.

= the ship sailed back in a safe manner. This implies that all due caution was observed.

Compare

He arrived drunk - he arrived and he was drunk.

He arrived drunkenly - he arrived in a manner that suggested he had been drinking, although he could have been ill, dizzy, etc.